# How do I call a Local Variable from Outside of its Method in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

```
public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/");
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    MyData data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, MyData.class);

}

public static class MyData {
    String  total_market_cap_usd;
}
```

So what I need is to call this local variable "data" in a different class. So what I need is to somehow create a global variable with the same value as this  local one, the problem is that the class this local variable is made from doesn't allow anything but final before it so could someone please help me out here. I'm really stumped and I haven't been able to find any resources to help me.
I'm sorry if I sound like a complete noob here because my experience in lower level coding languages is limited.

Comment: This reads like a classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you "need... to somehow create a global variable", there's a good chance you're taking the wrong approach... can you zoom out and explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't. If you want to use it elsewhere then declare is global or pass it to the next method.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is to create a chatbot which when asked a certain question, will check this api for the string called total_market_cap_usd and give it to the user.

Comment: @BryceHoward returning the value to next method would be the best. Else did you try out with _extends_ (inheritance) ?

Comment: This question is a masterpiece of unclear. What local variable? Of what class? Access from where? What is the name of the local variable? Classes don't have local variables, they have member variables AKA fields. What exactly are you trying to do? What error are you getting? Where does the reference to `final` come from? Please provide the code that tries to do what you need to do and show the error message and the location of the error.

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. If you want to access it from outside the scope, it can't be local to that scope. Surely this obvious?

Comment: @Arkadiy Im sorry for being unclear. I messed up my terminology. Basically what I meant is the local variable data is the variable I need to use in a different class to call in an array. I think you are entirely misunderstanding what I am asking. I'm asking someone to help me add something to my code, not fix it. If you can't understand what I'm asking just let others handle it please, as I said my knowledge of lower level coding languages is limited and I am not perfect by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement you mentioned in comment, I tried achieving. See if it helps.

```
public class ChatBot {
String response;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatBot c1 = new ChatBot();
    String qry1 = c1.getResponse("total_market_cap_usd");
    System.out.println("response: "+qry1);
}
public static class MyData {
    String total_market_cap_usd;
    String total_24h_volume_usd;
}
public String getResponse(String query) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        MyData data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, MyData.class);
        switch (query) {
        case "total_market_cap_usd":
            response = data.total_24h_volume_usd;
            break;
        case "total_24h_volume_usd":
            response = data.total_24h_volume_usd;
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Query not recognized!");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this helps a lot. I like the flexibility as well.I am going to implement this into an array and use that as the database for a chatbot so this is a great starting point.

Comment: @BryceHoward Please up-vote if it helped and click on the tick mark to accept the answer if it resolved your query. Thanks! ;-)

Comment: Alright thanks. obviously I'm new here. I upvoted your answer but since I have low rep it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html
Since you wish to use your variable in a different class,you can use *extends* keyword as:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
//you can override the implementation
  //@Override
  public void getVariable(){
    <datatype> var = this.localVariableOfPreviousClass;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.